# Meteor last executed query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Meteor Mongo and Mongodb query is doest same. I am using external Mongodb. so I need to debug my query. **Is their any way to find last executed query in Mongo?**

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this works in meteor mongo -but you seem to be using an external mongo - presumably you set up profiling with a capped collection, so that the collection never grows over a certain size. If you only need the last op, then you make the size pretty much smaller than this.

```
db.createCollection( "system.profile", { capped: true, size:4000000 } )
```

The mongo doc is here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

From the mongo docs:

> To return the most recent 10 log entries in the system.profile
>   collection, run a query similar to the following:
>
> ```
> db.system.profile.find().limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()
> ```

Since it's sorted inversely by time, just take the first record from the result.

Otherwise you could roll your own with a temporary client-only mongo collection:

```
Queries = new Mongo.Collection(null);
```

Create an object containing your query, cancel the last record and insert the new one.